# How do I link this image in my website to another url using an <a> tag?

Tags: html

I need to link this image in my website to another url but I cannot figure it out. I tried to use an `<a>` tag but when it deployed, I would click on the link and it still wouldn't redirect me. I'll attach the code below:

```
<div class="portfolio-item padd-15">
          <div class="portfolio-item-inner shadow-dark">
            <div class="portfolio-img">
              <img src="images/CGS Official Logo 500 × 360 px.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You apparently already know you need to use a `<a>` tag... so I would suggest you search for a tutorial.  This is very basic level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add an image to an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035772/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-an-html-file)

Comment: Yes, I do. I believe I just misplaced the closing </a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

To add a link to your `img` tag surround it with your anchor tags.

See this snippet:

```html
<div class="portfolio-item padd-15">
  <div class="portfolio-item-inner shadow-dark">
    <div class="portfolio-img">
       <a href="https://google.com">
         <img src="images/CGS Official Logo 500 × 360 px.png" alt="image">
       </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added alt text so you can see the URL functioning as intended.

[W3schools  tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Answer (score 0):

putting the `img` inside an anchor tag`<a>` `<img>` `</a>`

```css
img {
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item padd-15">
  <div class="portfolio-item-inner shadow-dark">
    <div class="portfolio-img">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1663668244836-68998f4e9151?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```